# How to change top position of linearLayout in ReletiveLayout progammaticlly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to change linearlayout that inside of ReletiveLayout.
But when I use settop it doesn't work!!!
and I can't find good tutorial

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:padding="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/remotebox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/remote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="WWWWWWWWWWW"
        android:textSize="30dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TTTTTT" 
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

i want change "@+id/remotebox" layout position and width and hight.
any suggestion about this problem or link of good tutorial?
sorry for poor english

Comment: where you want to put the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
   LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.remotebox);
    linearLayout.getLayoutParams().width=50;//dimensions
    linearLayout.requestLayout(); 
    linearLayout.setTranslationY(800);//position
```

hope this will help you .

Comment: @SiweiShen申思维 : I don't really remember the case but try to change it in ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener ... it should work.

Comment: I don't know why, but your answer is excellent. maybe my case is not the same with others.   Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the following code works :

```
    // step1.  get the target view
    LinearLayout thisView = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab3_bind_device_page);
    // step2. get the LayoutPrams instance. 
    // notice: in this case, the LinearLayout is wrapped by this RelativeLayout, 
    // so here we have to use the RelativeLayout.LayourParams
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    // change the margins 
    // in fact you should convert -25f from "px" to "dp", if possible.
    lp.setMargins(0, -25f, 0, 0);

    thisView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```